# Importing Time and Date

Tags: python, date, user-interface, tkinter, time

First time playing with Tkinter and using a bit of code I found on the web I'm going to build a basic App to get my head around the terminology used. I want to import the Date and Time into my GUI window. I have managed to get the time to appear in the window, but no such luck with the date. I can get the date to print in the command line and that's it.

I know this will be simple for somebody and any help would be appreciated. I'm using Python 2.7. Hope I'm using this website right!! Cheers, B.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from datetime import datetime 
import ttk

username = ("admin")
password = ("")


def try_login():
    print("Trying to login...")
    if username_guess.get() == username:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("COMPLETE", "You Have Now Logged In.", icon="info")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("-- ERROR --", "Please enter valid infomation!", icon="warning")

#Gui Things
window = Tk()

#Creating the username & password entry boxes
username_text = Label(text="Username:", bg='lightgrey')
username_guess = Entry()
password_text = Label(text="Password:", bg='lightgrey')
password_guess = Entry(show="*")
#attempt to login button
attempt_login = Button(text="Login", command=try_login)
attempt_login.pack(side="bottom", fill='none', expand=False, ipadx=0, ipady=0)

username_text.pack()
username_guess.pack()
password_text.pack()
password_guess.pack()
attempt_login.pack()

#Main Starter
window.mainloop()

##time1 = ''
##clock = Label(font=('times', 10, 'bold'), bg='lightgrey')
##clock.pack(side="bottom", fill='both', expand=False, ipadx=0, ipady=0)
##
##
##def tick():
##    global time1
##    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
##    if time2 != time1:
##        time1 = time2
##    clock.config(text=time2)
##    clock.after(200, tick)
##tick()
```

Comment: You say you have successfully got the time. Please show us the code.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code I used to import the time at the end of the code, I have commented it out as I don't think its the right code to use.

Comment: You imported datetime but have not done anything with that import. 2nd the code you do have to try and set up a clock is past the mainloop and wont do anything here. You cannot have GUI elements past the mainloop. That code will not run until the program has been closed.

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question to working code. By doing this, the question becomes very confusing because you seem to have working code already. If you feel the way you managed to make it work is interesting to share please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown what you have tried to get the time, so I don't know what your methods have been so far, but using the `time` module, you can get the date and time easily. Including formatting nicely, here is an easy way to get the date and time:

```
import time
d_and_t=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
```

For information on how this works, see [the time module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).
Here is an example of making a tkinter clock which updates every second:

```
from time import localtime, strftime, sleep #import various time functions
from tkinter import * #import tkinter
def disp(root): #a time updating function
    Label(root, text=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime()), fg='green', bg='purple', font=('Times', 20, 'bold')).grid(row=0, column=0) #see below explanation
    root.after(1000, lambda:disp(root)) #after 1 second, run this again
root=Tk() #create a window
root.title('Clock') #title it Clock
disp(root) #start the updating process
mainloop() #start the tkinter mainloop
```

Explanation of line 4:

- `Label(...)` - create a label instance
- `root` - attch it to the main window
- `text=strftime(...)` - the text is assigned to some time-formmatted text
- `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` - how we format the time: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
- `localtime()` - returns the local time
- `fg='green', bg='purple', font=('Times', 20, 'bold')` - format the text as green, purple background, Bold Times font, 20 points
- `.grid(row=0, column=0)` - place it in the same place as every time so that it goes on top

Comment: Thanks for the edits much appreciated. I have added the code I used to import the time at the end of the code, I've commented it out as I don't think its the right way to do it. Once again thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you should press the green tick next to it to mark it as a working solution. You will get 2 rep and I will get 15.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to create one label and update it instead of creating a new label every second?